# BASH: Read lines from netcat connection

Tags: bash, netcat

I have a simple script which reads some lines from a connection initialized using netcat. A client can transmit some "commands". If the client write "exit" I like to close the connection.

BUT: After transmit the "exit" the script echos the "Received 'exit'" but still reads **one** more line before the "Good bye" appears.

```
echo "Start listening on port $PORT ..."
    (echo "Welcome. Please give me one of the following commands: 
            $AVAILABLECOMMANDS") | nc -q -1 -l $PORT | while read line
    do
            if [ "$line" == 'exit' ]; then
                    echo "Received 'exit'"
                    break
            else
                    result=$(executeCommand $line)
                    echo "$result"
            fi
    done
    echo "Good bye"
```

I think I have to rewrite the loop but I have no idea how.

Can somebody help?

Thank you.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What are you using for the client? I tried with `netcat` on the other end and an `exit` immediately ended the loop.

Comment: For the client I'm using **nc Raspbian 9999**. Also tried using netcat, but makes no difference

Comment: [`nc`, `netcat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html), to-may-to to-mah-to.

Comment: Ok, was not sure if its the same command :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166546/bash-cannot-break-out-of-piped-while-read-loop-process-substitution-works), bash made the choice to exit only when all the commands in the pipe as ended. Here, `netcat` does not want to stop, but after since the end pipe is broken, `netcat` fails. That's why you need to wait one more time to quit the loop (by the way, you have an error when you quit the loop). Here is a version that doesn't have this pipe problem :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start listening on port 12345 ..."
while read line
do
    if [ "$line" == 'exit' ]; then
        echo "Received 'exit'"
        break
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < <((echo "Welcome. Please give me one of the following commands: $AVAILABLECOMMANDS") | nc -q -1 -l 12345)
echo "Good bye"
```

Comment: Thank you. That works (but you have to pass the -l option to nc command ;))

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm using Fedora, and the netcat version doesn't use -q -1, and when I manually added it, I remove the -l option (don't know why). Edited !

Answer (score 2):

Handy way to get incoming data and transmit data over netcat.

```
#!/bin/bash

netcat -l localhost 12345  # port 12345
exec 6<>/dev/tcp/localhost/12345

while read <&6
do
        echo "$REPLY"
done
```

Comment: Why do you need a read/write  on  file  descriptor 6 ?